# Why can I no longer break into doors in Deus Ex?

Tags: deus-ex

This time, the game does work, but I can't break into doors. I could only do it twice, once with a 10mm gun and the other with the crowbar. Now when I have the option to break into a door, the health doesn't decrease not even when I attack it with my crowbar.

The doors weren't 100% buggy, though. I had the option to lockpick the doors, but I can't do it due to the lack of lockpicks in my inventory.

I am aware that there are doors which you can't break into (those with INF HP), but the others with limited door resistance should be allowed to be broken into. I made sure that the door I was breaking into wasn't an INF one, so I have no idea why I can't break into doors now.

TL;DR, I *can* lockpick doors, but not *break into* them.

Side note: I looked at this question here: [What damages doors?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61654/what-damages-doors), however, this did not help, as I tried to break into them with some of the methods. I'm in the "Hell's Kitchen" level, so explosives aren't an option, at least from what I could see.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Door Strength bar on the doors in Deus Ex doesn't show Hit Points, but a threshold: it shows **the minimal damage you need to apply** in one go in order to break it down.

This forces you to make strategic choices: do I blow up doors to get an advantage (in the form of items, or shortcuts, or information) alarming everyone to my presence, do I look around for lockpicks, potentially fruitlessly, and sneak in, while increasing the chances of being caught, or do I just bypass the entrance altogether?

I have also on several occasions blasted open a door remotely and waited out the alerted enemies so I could sneak back and enter or steal what's behind the door.

Comment: With max skill, the Dragontooth sword can chop open all doors that are not INF. The Crossbow can do pretty high, I think around 60% or so. LAMs and GEP gun can obviously just blow them up regardless of your skill with them. If you want explosions that open doors without alerting anyone (or even aggroing neutral units), use the explosive boxes; throw them into the air, and duck behind cover.

Comment: @Nelson All the information about what weapons can be used to break open doors can be found through the link in the question.